# ckeditor - many br in table cells

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

ckeditor is new to me.

ckeditor is used for email content edit of my aspx page
however it is OK to view by IE11 but not OK by Outlook 2013
i find there are many BR in the table cells 
is it OK to use ckeditor for email purpose
Thanks a lot.

---

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px"><br>
<tbody><br>
<tr><br><td>a</td><br><td>b</td><br></tr><br>
<tr><br><td>c</td><br><td>d</td><br></tr><br>
<tr><br><td>1</td><br><td>2</td><br></tr><br>
</tbody><br></table><br>
```

---

```
CKEDITOR.on('TxtMessage', function (ev) {
    ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules('br',
     {
         indent: false,
         breakBeforeOpen: false,
         breakAfterOpen: false,
         breakBeforeClose: false,
         breakAfterClose: false
     });
});
config.autoParagraph = false;
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You set enterMode and shiftEnterMode to **CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR** it is reason have  many `<br>` in the table.

Read more at https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/ck-editor-enter-mode